# All the pixels in an image exported from Earth Engine have the same value

Tags: raster, google-earth-engine, rasterio, google-earth-engine-python-api, pixel

I'm trying to export an image with 42 bands from Google Earth Engine:
Some bands correspond to an index like NDBI for Sentinel 2 images and his equivalent for Sentinel 1 images, other band correspond to the places with water and other with the roads.

```py
country = 'Dominican Republic'
countries = ee.FeatureCollection("USDOS/LSIB/2017")
countryName = ee.Filter.eq('COUNTRY_NA', country)
regionPred = countries.filter(countryName)
region = countries.filter(countryName)

...

stacked_ndbi = ndb1.addBands(
    [TCI, ndb2, ndb3, ndb4, ndb5, ndb6, ndb7, ndb8, ndb9, ndb10, ndb11, ndb12, 
     waterDataset, sarui1, sarui2, sarui3, sarui4, sarui5, sarui6, sarui7, sarui8,
     sarui9, sarui10, sarui11, sarui12, uai1, uai2, uai3, uai4, uai5, uai6, uai7, 
     uai8, uai9, uai10, uai11, uai12, imageRoads]).clip(region)

projection = stacked_ndbi.getInfo()['bands'][0]
crs = projection['crs']
transform = projection['crs_transform']

export_format = {
    'training': {
        'image': stacked_ndbi.toFloat(),
        'description': 'stacked_ndbi',
        'folder': 'folder',
        'crs': crs,
        'crsTransform': transform,
        'fileFormat': 'GeoTIFF',
        'region': region,
        'maxPixels': 1e13,
        'scale': 10,
        'skipEmptyTiles': True
    }
}
task_training = ee.batch.Export.image.toDrive(**export_format['training'])
task_training.start()
```

In this example I try to export the image with the 42 bands but I also tried to export every bands as single image, even using smaller regions.

The problem is when I do the following, where labeled contains small geometries:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame()

folder = '../data/folder'

files = os.listdir(folder)

rasters = [f for f in files if f.endswith('.tif')]

all_df = []
for raster in tqdm(rasters):
    raster_file_path = os.path.join(folder, raster)

    with rasterio.open(raster_file_path) as src:
        band_names = src.descriptions 
        dataframes = [] 
        for _, row in labeled.iterrows():
            
            try:
                out_image, out_transform = mask(src, [row.geometry], crop=True, all_touched=True, nodata=-999)
                if np.all(out_image == 0):
                    continue
                temp_data = {"class": row['class']}
                for i, band_name in enumerate(band_names):
                    print(f"Band {band_name}", out_image[i].flatten())
            except IndexError as ie:
                print(ie)
                break
            except Exception as e:
                continue
```

I always get the same output:

```
Band NDBI1 [-0.0360934 -0.0360934 -0.0360934 -0.0360934 -0.0360934 -0.0360934]
Band B3 [0.04255 0.04255 0.04255 0.04255 0.04255 0.04255]
Band B4 [0.037 0.037 0.037 0.037 0.037 0.037]
Band B2 [0.0516 0.0516 0.0516 0.0516 0.0516 0.0516]
Band NDBI2 [-0.06450588 -0.06450588 -0.06450588 -0.06450588 -0.06450588 -0.06450588]
Band NDBI3 [-0.04505971 -0.04505971 -0.04505971 -0.04505971 -0.04505971 -0.04505971]
Band NDBI4 [-0.05496536 -0.05496536 -0.05496536 -0.05496536 -0.05496536 -0.05496536]
Band NDBI5 [-0.04487657 -0.04487657 -0.04487657 -0.04487657 -0.04487657 -0.04487657]
Band NDBI6 [-0.04924241 -0.04924241 -0.04924241 -0.04924241 -0.04924241 -0.04924241]
Band NDBI7 [-0.0306486 -0.0306486 -0.0306486 -0.0306486 -0.0306486 -0.0306486]
Band NDBI8 [-0.02052786 -0.02052786 -0.02052786 -0.02052786 -0.02052786 -0.02052786]
Band NDBI9 [-0.05775921 -0.05775921 -0.05775921 -0.05775921 -0.05775921 -0.05775921]
Band NDBI10 [-0.08153077 -0.08153077 -0.08153077 -0.08153077 -0.08153077 -0.08153077]
Band NDBI11 [-0.07234885 -0.07234885 -0.07234885 -0.07234885 -0.07234885 -0.07234885]
Band NDBI12 [-0.08059212 -0.08059212 -0.08059212 -0.08059212 -0.08059212 -0.08059212]
```

As you can see every pixel captured by the geometry has the same value but I also see that:

```py
print(src.read(1))
```

The output is a matrix where every value is the same.